# I want a pageblocksection to be visible only when the checkebox is clicked

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes

Here is my code. This is supposed to display column1 when checkbox1 is clicked, and so on. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>A</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" onclick="myFunction('checkbox1', 'column1')" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>P</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox2" onclick="myFunction('checkbox2', 'column2')" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>O</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox3" onclick="myFunction('checkbox3', 'column3')"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="3" title="Account Detail pop-up">
            <apex:outputPanel id="column1" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.OwnerId}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel id="column2" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Phone}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel id="column3" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Type}" />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Industry}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<script>
    function myFunction(checkboxId, columnId) {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
        var text = document.getElementById(columnId);

        if (checkBox.checked) {
            text.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            text.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

</apex:page>

Comment: the normal VF pattern would be to use `actionSupport` and `rerender` and not use `style="display:none"`

Answer (score -2):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>A</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox1" onclick="myFunction('checkbox1', 'column1')" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>P</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox2" onclick="myFunction('checkbox2', 'column2')" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>O</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox3" onclick="myFunction('checkbox3', 'column3')" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:outputPanel id="column1" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!$Component.checkbox1.checked}">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.OwnerId}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel id="column2" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!$Component.checkbox2.checked}">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Phone}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel id="column3" style="display:none;">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" rendered="{!$Component.checkbox3.checked}">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Type}" />
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Industry}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <script>
        function myFunction(checkboxId, columnId) {
            var checkBox = document.getElementById(checkboxId);
            var text = document.getElementById(columnId);

            if (checkBox.checked) {
                text.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                text.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Kindly let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I've downvoted this because it is a _code dump_ (only code, no explanation as to how/why it works). Code dumps are of limited value. Adding a detailed explanation as to _what_ the initial issue is, _how_ this approach overcomes that, and _why_ it works would greatly improve this answer.